# Spring boot calling external ElasticSearch instance

Tags: spring-data-elasticsearch

I have a spring boot (jhipster) application and need it to connect to an external elasticsearch instance. For this I need to configure the correct username and password. However I am not able to find any documentation on this. All examples I found are running elasticsearch locally without a password.

```
spring:
    data:
        elasticsearch:
            cluster-name:
            cluster-nodes: my.own.ip.adr:9300
```

How do I specify a username and password?